# Rearranging column order depending on different delimiters

Tags: bash, shell, csv, awk

I wrote a Bash script that receives input file, output file, delimter and column names in order to allow user to enter desired column arrangement by column name and get that arrangement in the output file. It also allows user to choose whether to discard the rest of the columns by writing yes or no for the discard argument (see examples below).

Example input file:

```
Name    Age Pets
Alice   32  Fluffy
Bob 45  Whiskers
Charlie 27  Buddy
```

Example user command:

```
bash arrange.sh  pets_rearranged.tsv no pets.tsv Age Name
```

Example output:

```
Age Name        Pets
32  Alice       Fluffy
45  Bob     Whiskers
27  Charlie     Buddy
```

My script:

```
#!/bin/bash

name=$1
discard=$2
input=$3

cmd=("$@")

my_list=()

for (( i=3; i<${#cmd[@]}; i++ )); do
    my_list+=( $(awk -v RS='\t' 'tolower($0) ~ tolower("'"${cmd[$i]}"'") {print NR; exit}' $input) );
done

list=$(echo "${my_list[@]}")

awk -vd="$list" 'BEGIN{split(d, a, " ")} {for (i in a) printf "%s\t", $(a[i]); printf "\n"}' $input > first.txt

if [ $2 == 'no' ]
then
  cut -f"${list}" --complement $input > last.txt
else
  touch last.txt
fi

paste first.txt last.txt > $name
```

The script works perfectly with TSV files, but I would like to make it work for other delimiter as well, for example comma or hash, however when I change delimiter in script it no longer works, I don't understand why:

```
#!/bin/bash
    
    name=$1
    discard=$2
    input=$3
    
    cmd=("$@")
    
    my_list=()
    
    for (( i=3; i<${#cmd[@]}; i++ )); do
        my_list+=( $(awk -v RS='#' 'tolower($0) ~ tolower("'"${cmd[$i]}"'") {print NR; exit}' $input) );
    done
    
    list=$(echo "${my_list[@]}")
    
    awk -vd="$list" 'BEGIN{split(d, a, " ")} {for (i in a) printf "%s#", $(a[i]); printf "\n"}' $input > first.txt
    
    if [ $2 == 'no' ]
    then
      cut -f"${list}" --complement -d'#' $input > last.txt
    else
      touch last.txt
    fi
    
    paste first.txt last.txt > $name
```

In this case, for input:

```
CHR#NUM1#NUM2
chr22#9999999#10001000
chr22#10009999#10010100
```

I get output:

```
#CHR#NUM1#NUM2#
#chr22#9999999#10001000#
#chr22#10009999#10010100#
```

For command:

```
bash arrange.sh  hash_rearranged.tsv no hash.tsv NUM1 CHR
```

I would like to achieve for script to work with different delimiters.

Comment: Eric Lippert has an excellent blog post, [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/), that may be helpful to you.

Comment: Don't substitute `${cmd[$i]}` directly into the `awk` script. See [how do I use shell variables in an awk script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19075671/how-do-i-use-shell-variables-in-an-awk-script)

Comment: It will almost certainly be easier to do this whole thing in `awk`, rather than going back and forth from `awk` to `bash`.

Comment: FWIW, I don't think `RS=...` can be what you want: `RS` is for separating *records* -- it defaults to being a newline -- not for separating *fields* (within a record).

Comment: @ruakh yeah, thanks, I tried with FS as well figuring that that might be an issue but I get the same output

Comment: I'd just use `csvcut` from the [csvkit bundle of utilities](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Comment: You should copy/paste your script into http://shellcheck.net and fix the issues it'll tell you about.

Answer (score 1):

Using any awk:

```
$ cat arrange.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

outfile=$1
discard=$2
infile=$3
shift 3

inFldSep="${fldSep:-\t}"
outFldSep="${outFldSep:-$inFldSep}"

awk -F"$inFldSep" -v OFS="$outFldSep" -v discard="$discard" -v tgts="$*" '
    NR == 1 {
        numOutFlds = split(tgts,outNrs2tags," ")
        for ( outFldNr=1; outFldNr<=numOutFlds; outFldNr++ ) {
            tag = outNrs2tags[outFldNr]
            tags2outNrs[tag] = outFldNr
        }

        for ( inFldNr=1; inFldNr<=NF; inFldNr++ ) {
            tag = $inFldNr
            tags2inNrs[tag] = inFldNr
            if ( discard == "no" ) {
                if ( !(tag in tags2outNrs) ) {
                    outNrs2tags[++numOutFlds] = tag
                }
            }
        }

        for ( outFldNr=1; outFldNr<=numOutFlds; outFldNr++ ) {
            tag = outNrs2tags[outFldNr]
            inFldNr = tags2inNrs[tag]
            out2in[outFldNr] = inFldNr
        }
    }
    {
        for ( outFldNr=1; outFldNr<=numOutFlds; outFldNr++ ) {
            inFldNr = out2in[outFldNr]
            printf "%s%s", $inFldNr, (outFldNr<numOutFlds ? OFS : ORS)
        }
    }
' "$infile" > "$outfile"
```

```
$ ./arrange.sh pets_rearranged.tsv no pets.tsv Age Name
```

```
$ cat pets_rearranged.tsv
Age     Name    Pets
32      Alice   Fluffy
45      Bob     Whiskers
27      Charlie Buddy
```

```
$ fldSep='#' ./arrange.sh hash_rearranged.tsv no hash.tsv NUM1 CHR
```

```
$ cat hash_rearranged.tsv
NUM1#CHR#NUM2
9999999#chr22#10001000
10009999#chr22#10010100
```

```
$ fldSep='#' ./arrange.sh hash_rearranged.tsv yes hash.tsv NUM1 CHR
```

```
$ cat hash_rearranged.tsv
NUM1#CHR
9999999#chr22
10009999#chr22
```

The above can do more than your current script can do, including convert field separators:

```
$ cat hash.tsv
CHR#NUM1#NUM2
chr22#9999999#10001000
chr22#10009999#10010100
```

```
$ fldSep='#' outFldSep='\t' ./arrange.sh hash_rearranged.tsv no hash.tsv
```

```
$ cat hash_rearranged.tsv
CHR     NUM1    NUM2
chr22   9999999 10001000
chr22   10009999        10010100
```

and do it more robustly, more portably, and more efficiently, but it needs more work still if you want to be able to handle a full range of character-separated files that follow similar rules to CSVs, including support for the separator character and newlines appearing inside quoted fields. See [What's the most robust way to efficiently parse CSV using awk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45420535/whats-the-most-robust-way-to-efficiently-parse-csv-using-awk) for more information.

I wouldn't have chosen the interface above where you have to set variables outside of the script that are known inside the script to change the in/out field separators, I'd be using the POSIX standard `-argument [option]` API and a `getopts` loop to parse them, but I didn't want to change your current API, you can do that if you like.

Comment: You;re welcome, please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers for what to do next and feel free to ask any questions.

Answer (score 1):

The generally accepted format for CSV and TSV files includes quoting rules, which you really  do not want to be attempting in awk or bash. There are tons and tons of tools for dealing with CSV and TSV files, here is a small selection:

https://github.com/secretGeek/AwesomeCSV

Here is the generally accepted definition of a CSV file:

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4180